# Syntax Error in Insert Into Statement VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net, syntax, insert

I'm having the following Error Message on data insertion: `Syntax Error in Insert into Statement`

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong please?

**Remark**: Field [No] is Primary Key and Data Type is Auto-Increment.

```
    con.Open()
    Dim tblRoom_Add As String

    tblRoom_Add = "INSERT INTO tblRoom1(No ,Room ,Check_In ,Check_Out ,User ,Price) VALUES " & _
   "('1', '1A', '10-5-2014', '10-6-2014', 'NaNa', '45')"

    Dim InsertInvoice = New OleDbCommand
    InsertInvoice = New OleDbCommand(tblRoom_Add, con)
    InsertInvoice.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Which DBMS is this? `user` is a keyword in SQL Server, so you would need to escape it like `[user]`.

Comment: its ACCESS and he is right

Comment: Its Ms Access Database

Answer (score 1):

If this is MS Access `NO` and `USER` are  reserved words. You either could use a differnt column name or wrap them in brackets`[]`

```
INSERT INTO tblRoom1([No], ...., [User], ...
```

[Access 2007 reserved words and symbols](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

its not like mysql integers and numbers should not be surronded by `'` try this :

```
 tblRoom_Add = "INSERT INTO tblRoom1(No ,Room ,Check_In ,Check_Out ,[User] ,Price) VALUES (1, '1A', '10-5-2014', '10-6-2014', 'NaNa', 45)"
```